# preg_match function is returning only false value

Tags: php, regex, deployment, backend, session-cookies

I am trying to match user entered words with the patterns stored in the $patterns array, but preg_match function is returning only false value.

```
<?php
    $patterns = array(
        "p1"=>array("/^t[a-z]*s$/i","start with 't' and end with 's'"),
        "p2"=>array("/^c[a-z]*e$/i","start with 'c' and end with 'e'"),
        "p3"=>array("/^p[a-z]*t$/i"," start with 'p' and end with 't'"),
        "p4"=>array("/^b[a-z]*y$/i"," start with 'b' and end with 'y'"),
        "p5"=>array("/^w[a-z]*r$/i","start with 'w' and end with 'r'"),
        "p6"=>array("/^d[a-z]*n$/i","start with 'd' and end with 'n'"));
$randomKey = array_rand($patterns);
// print_r($patterns[$random]);
// print_r($patterns);
// print_r($patterns[$randomKey][0]);
// print_r($patterns[$randomKey][1]);
$randomValue1 = $patterns[$randomKey][0];
$randomValue2 = $patterns[$randomKey][1];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Word Challange</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4">Word Challange Game</h1>
    <h3>Enter a Word that <?php echo $randomValue2?> </h3>
       <form method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="word" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter a word">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
            <!-- <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary"></input> -->
        </form>
<?php
        session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
            $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
        }
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            if(isset($_POST['word'])){
                $word=$_POST['word'];
                if(preg_match($randomValue1,$word)){
                    $_SESSION['score']++;
                    echo "Correct :) </br>";
                    echo "Score: ".$_SESSION['score'];
                }
                else{
                    echo "!!Incorrect Input!! Game Over :(</br>";
                    echo "Your Score: ".$_SESSION['score'];
                    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
                }
                // echo "</br>".$patterns[$GLOBALS['random']][0];
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to randomly select the pattern and pattern message.

Comment: Please make sure your code is formatted properly when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not always. If you type in a correct answer and after the POST the same pattern is randomized as the previous one, then you will get a Correct answer :)

The issue is that once you POST your word, the page reloads and the POSTed word is tested against the newly randomized pattern rather than the pattern that was asked before the POST. In order to make sure it works, you will need to be aware of what the pattern was before the POST and test against that rather than the pattern you have randomized after the POST. I achieved it with a session variable called `$_SESSION['pattern']`:

```
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            if(isset($_SESSION['pattern'])){
                    $word=$_POST['word'];
                    echo var_dump($_POST['word']);
                if(preg_match($_SESSION['pattern'],$word)){
                    $_SESSION['score']++;
                    echo "Correct :) </br>";
                    echo "Score: ".$_SESSION['score'];
                }
                else{
                    echo "!!Incorrect Input!! Game Over :(</br>";
                    echo "Your Score: ".$_SESSION['score'];
                    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
                }
                // echo "</br>".$patterns[$GLOBALS['random']][0];
            }
            $_SESSION['pattern'] = $randomValue1;
        }
```

The above is just the part of the code where I needed to apply changes.